# sapply in R, how to use?

Tags: r, sapply

I am a C++ programmer and I am new to R. Somebody told me that using a for loop in R is a bad idea and that it is better to use `sapply`. I wrote the following code to calculate the probability of a [birthday coincidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem):

```
prob <- 1           # prob of no coincidence
days <- 365 
k <- 50             # how many people
probability <- numeric()  #probability vector (empty right now)
for(i in 1:k){
    prob <- (days - i + 1)/days * prob # Formula for no coincidence
    probability[i] <- 1 - prob
}
```

How I can do the same thing with `sapply`? I want to do something like:

```
1 - sapply(1:length(m), function(x) prod(m[1:x]))
```

But how to use the formula for no coincidence of birthday?

Comment: `m` is never defined.  What is it supposed to be?

Comment: Always beware of "somebody."  He's full of ideas but often without reliable attribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
m <- (days - seq_len(k) + 1) / days
probability <- 1 - sapply(seq_along(m), function(x) prod(m[1:x]))
```

but that would be missing on the useful `cumprod` function:

```
probability <- 1 - cumprod(m)
```

which will be a lot faster.

(Also gave you a peak at `seq_along` and `seq_len` which are more robust than `:` when dealing with zero-length vectors.)

Comment: Woow! so seq_along and seq_len are more faster than 1:something? also cumprod? Where I can learn to write good and faster code with R? Thanks!

Comment: Also, what if I want to print some interation? for example when the probability is less than 50% ? I know how to do it in a for, but how with sapply? or cumprod? @flodel

Comment: `seq_along` and `seq_len` are not faster, they are safer: see what `1:x` give you when `x` is zero. If you want to print cases where `prob` is `< 0.5`, you can 1) modify the function you `sapply`, e.g. `function(x){y <- prod(m[1:x]); if (y < 50) print(x); return(y)}` or 2) again, use something vectorized: `which(probability < 0.5)`.

Answer (score 4):

For you specific question it's probably best to just use the built-in birthday probability calculator

```
sapply(1:50, pbirthday)
```

Comment: Brilliant. Someone's covering every eventuality.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to do it just to get more info and experience with R.

Comment: @Edwardo you could take a look at the source code for `pbirthday` to see how the author attacked this probability problem.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft How I can see the source code of pbirthday in R?

Comment: @Edwardo Just type `pbirthday`

Comment: I dont understand what they are doing there! :/ but thanks anyway! @CarlWitthoft